# how to add a argument to a line number using sed linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file with the line:

```
.....
30145: $RM "$cfgfile"
.....
```

How i can add a '-f' argument to before $RM in this specific line like this using sed:

```
.....
30145: $RM -f "$cfgfile"
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use & to represent whatever string has been matched:

```
sed '/30145/s/$RM/& -f/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using:

```
sed -i filename -e '30145s!$RM!$RM -f!'
```

Thanks

Comment: Cool, but please note that the option argument to `-i` is a filename _extension_ appended to the _original_ filename, not a filename in its own right. Also, while the `-e` doesn't hurt, it's not necessary here (use `-e` to specify multiple commands / parts of a script as separate arguments).

Comment: @mklement0 thank you for your great comment. greetings